# Burninate [real]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Trogdor will be our saviour in this time of need!

The [real](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/real) tag is often used together with the [time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time) tag to create a substitute for [real-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/real-time) and only adds to the confusion when all three tags are combined into a unholy concoction.

[real](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/real)

- No wiki entry.
- 87 questions.
- 5 followers.
- In desperate need of [real](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/real)OGs.

EDIT: Further reasons for removal, as presented in the [comment section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267890/burninate-real?noredirect=1#comment73273_267890):

> The tag is used as:
>
> 1) a partial tag
>
> 2) modifier on another tag
>
> 3) general emphasis
>
> 4) substitute for floating-point
>
> 5) As the floating-point data-type real (should be substituted with 4 anyway)

Is there any need for this tag?

Comment: Additionally, no-one can be an expert on "real". Because reality is toooo biiig.

Comment: Has a duplicate on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199495/burninate-the-real-tag

Comment: I find the "evidence" for this to be less than convincing. You basically want to berninate a tag because it gets misused. It's too obvious that low rep users will "tag" a question as anything that will stick. Maybe you should thumb through and flag redundant or mistagged posts.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils So this tag has reasons to exist?

Comment: Yes, if not for any other reason that any pretty well respected user has the right to make a tag. Real, has a meaning in CS *other* than the antithesis of fake. Real numbers for example. Any post, IMHO, that is tagged both real, time, and real-time should be edited. Did you look at the five followers of this tag?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils If the needed tag is `real-numbers`, then why use the `real` tag at all? Is there some big connection between `real-time`, `real-numbers`, and `real-slim-shady` I am not seeing?

Comment: Maybe I'm going blind but I can't see where these 5 followers are displayed. Are you two talking about the top answerers that are shown?

Comment: NO @Stijn, follow the about link in the tag; it will show the few followers.

Comment: Basically the point is those who understand its use, use it correctly. BTW I didn't mean to yell there :)

Comment: @MarcusWigert, there is no `real-numbers` tag. How am I supposed to answer a question that begs the connection between three, two of which being `fake`, tags?

Comment: @MarcusWigert There's excellent reason to burn this tag with fire, but you don't present it: The tag is used as 1) a **partial tag** 2) **modifier** on another tag 3) **general emphasis** 4) substitute for [tag:floating-point] 5) As the floating-point data-type `real` (should be substituted with 4 anyway) Please amend your request.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils "any pretty well respected user has the right to make a tag" - and everybody else has the right to say "that tag is useless, let's remove it". As long as the tag has no positive effect, or worse, has a negative effect as seen here (being used for a lot of unrelated questions that somehow contain the word "real", from `mysql_real_escape_string` to "real world" and "real time"), it should be removed as it is noise. The only use that seems somewhat valid is for fortran reals, but they should either use the existing floating-point tag or a new "fortran-reals" tag.

Comment: That is true, however, you're not arguing a valid point. Again, people misuse the tag, so the people who don't follow the rules have more clout in determining the fate of a tag than do those who use it appropriately? You're wrong in your "seeming". It could be a synonym for `floating-point`, but to say they should use the new `fortran-reals` is a baseless and backwards approach to your argument. How would anyone apply that tag to a question which begs the handling of real numbers in C++, C#, Java, ...?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils By using the `real-numbers` tag.

Comment: Oh, you must mean [this real numbers tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/real-numbers), that's useful?? The point of the last comment is we have a user who suggests `real` has no positive, but in fact a negative, impact, based solely on misuse, on the site, only to suggest that a viable solution is to berninate this tag so we can commence with misusing, i.e.; `fortran-reals`, another one. If `real` is redundant, misused, or indeed guilty of all said things, then so is `fortran-reals`. Let's stay consistent, *at least*.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Well, I feel that you're the one who's not arguing a valid point here. Fact is, there is no _appropriate_ use of the tag because it is filled with unrelated crap. The fact that a few questions dealing with real numbers feel more appropriate than the rest of the crap does not mean that is a good usage. You can't argue for the intention of the tag either as it has no wiki. Thus it is effectively useless.

Comment: And regarding `fortran-reals`, such a tag should of course only be created if an existing tag such as `floating-point` or `decimal` wouldn't suffice. I don't know fortran and thus have no idea if there is anything special about its real datatype which would speak against tagging a question about fortran reals with e.g. `floating-point`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I feel like your creating facts out of opinion. Lack of a wiki, while unfortunate, may only broaden, but not invalidate, its use. You're suggesting if I edit that tag right now and provide a single line summary of the tag it somehow springs into usefulness. If that's all it takes why not take the plunge and edit it; could it be op, with their lack of rep, only has an option of burnination?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I never said the tag would become useful just by adding a wiki; but I said that currently you can't even know what it was originally intended for, which is one more reason you can't call any use of the tag "appropriate" (which is still different from "useful"). Personally, I would simply suggest removing the tag from every single question where it is currently used; it might be better to do so manually and attempt to re-tag questions appropriately, but that might not be worth the effort.

Comment: You did indirectly; the presence of the wiki gives basis to arguing its intent and therefore usefulness. The "fact' is the community owns that tag and if equal time was spent improving it, whatever that means, as is spent trying to get rid of it I'd have no issue. There's a clear use of `real` in the mathematical sense and different than `floating-point` approximations in the computational sense. Therefore, there's no doubt, in order to serve the entire community, a burnination request should be declined. Over-and-out!

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: You've claimed on multiple occasions that there is a correct interpretation of `real`, but you have never explained whether that's `real-number` or `real-time`. Nor have you argued why your interpretation is so superior to the other that `real` should be made a synonym.

Comment: @MSalters, I think because it's a community thing the intent can be determined by the post, specifically the older ones, as they are the tellers of the intent. As far as I'm willing to go back now, the posts all use it the way I make an ass out of myself with. Sorry, if I haven't made it clear enough, I'm talking numbers. My implementation isn't superior, especially not "so", but I think common sense is commonly disregarded for sake of argument and self-gratifying acts. A synonym is a, not surprsingly unwelcome, compromise.

Comment: I would propose first cleaning it up by removing and replacing all uses not synonymous to [tag:floating-point], and then synonymizing to that.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: Even with that response, I **still** cannot determine what you think is the right meaning. Furthermore, "synonym = compromise"?? I haven't seen any new meaning of `real`, all meanings mentioned already have unambiguous tags such as `real-time` or `floating-point`.

Comment: @MSalters, my right meaning came to me as intuition and then verified by researching it's usage and thus confirming it to that extent. Real is used, as I see it -  and as used early, as real numbers. Synonym != compromise, a compromise is something that is reached after numerous attempts to shed light on a subject without understanding. That could be my fault since Duplicator basically summed it up in a few words

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Real is a data type in [Fortran](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/REAL.html) and [Pascal](http://wiki.freepascal.org/real), so the tag should probably stay for those uses. I'm in the process of cleaning up any questions tagged [real](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/real) that are not also tagged with some variant of [fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran) or [pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pascal).

---

It's a keyword in SQL as well, but it's just a synonym for `float`, so I'm just going to replace those instances.

---

After cleaning up, I've went ahead and replaced the last instances of the tag [real](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/real) with [real-datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/real-datatype) where it applies.

Comment: [tag:real-datatype] instead of [tag:real]?

Comment: @Yakk Yes, it's probably worth creating that tag just to squash any ambiguity.

Comment: [real is also a system class in Common Lisp](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_real.htm)

Comment: Also a valid type in Modula-2.